# Put a <br> only within inline list element itself

Tags: html, css

I would like to put a line break into an inline list to produce this result:
[image]

However when I put a line break into my basic list, this is the result I get:
[image]

How would I make it so that I can put a br within the li element only without, messing up the horizontal list itself.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Bonjour</li>
  <li>Longer<br>text</li>
  <li>Aloha</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Next time use built-in code snippets. Avoid using external services ;P

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer JSFiddle is perfectly acceptable, and in fact, I prefer it as it allows me to edit the code easily.

Comment: @DrydenLong I believe that there's no discussion here. Built-in code snippets should be prioritized because they allow everyone to be sure that the whole runnable code sample will be here forever, while external services can disappear and make either questions or answer useless...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer From http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it/254430#254430 "Then post the code to reproduce the problem [...] as a live demonstration using Stack Snippets. As some people are more used to them, consider additionally providing it on JS Bin and/or jsFiddle. Since these are third party services and may be unavailable at any time, make sure your question can be understood without visiting these websites." Considering OP included his code in the post, I would say the jsfiddle link was sufficient

Comment: @DrydenLong BTW linked post isn't made by a staff member :/ Maybe the link was ok but this is a very very very very simple issue that could perfectly be reproduced with stack snippets so there's no justification to go to other site to test the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`display: inline-block;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) instead:

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Bonjour</li>
  <li>Longer<br>text</li>
  <li>Aloha</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of styling the li with

```
display:inline;
```

You could achieve the desired effect by

```
float:left;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use** `display: inline-block`

Here is working **snippet**

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
}

ul li{
  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Bonjour</li>
  <li>Longer<br>text</li>
  <li>Aloha</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: As soon as you set `float: left;` [you're implicitly setting `display: block;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)...

Comment: @AndréDion sorry ! i got you thanks :) i will update my answer.